# can't access usb modem after bridging modem

Tags: bridge, usb-modem

I have an air stream 1200 USB modem. I accidentally selected bridge mode and now I am not able to access the USB modem web interface. It gives me public IP directly. This modem came with only a USB port.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar, it's normal. The solution is to hold the reset button.

Comment: Where on the modem is the reset button located? How long does it need to be held down? Is it held down on power up, or while it is already powered on?

Comment: @JasonAller well, we tend not to go that device specific on this site in Qs or As, I wouldn't mind stating a general then adding a specific, i.e. stating the general then answering what you ask there, but I can't find the manual for the device.